# Django - Model to chose only 1 object from multiple objects

Tags: django, django-models

How to make a model with a **yes/no** field, if yes that particular object (image) will be used as the background, and no other image will be selected.

I have come with this model:

```
class BackgroundImage(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(user)
    caption = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_upload_file_name)
    using_image = models.BooleanField()
```

But with this I can select all of them, and not only one.

**Edit:**

Lets take an example of profile picture. A user can have many images, but he can only select one as a profile picture. So, that if he selects one, the others will be un-select itself. Hope everybody understood what I mean. Please ask me if didn't understood. Also please correct me if my model is not correct. Thank you!

Comment: Did you try to use choices field https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#choices

Comment: I think what your asking is for choicefield right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a `save()` hook to ensure no other `BackgroundImage` for the given user has the flag. (Also, you'll want that column to be `db_index=True` for performance reasons.)

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if self.use_image:
        BackgroundImage.objects.filter(user=self.user).update(use_image=False)
    super(BackgroundImage, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But, am a newbie. Could you please kindly elaborate a little more. :)